# Mongoose not updating the MongoDB document

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Here is the nodejs code I'm using to update the document in the mongoDB, req.body contains the document which was send as an post request to the nodejs server,
it is not throwing any errors but not updating the document too, any suggestions why this is happening;

```
    router.route('/results').post(function(req,res){
        var toupdate = req.body;
        delete toupdate._id;
        console.log(toupdate)
        Question.update({_id:req.body._id}, toupdate, function(err){
            if(err){
                console.error(err.stack);
            }
        });
// even tried Question.update({_id:req.body._id}, {$set:{questions:toupdate.question}});
    });
```

I also tried using findById and then saving the document this time got 500 as an response:

```
router.route('/results').post(function(req,res){
    var toupdate = req.body;
    delete toupdate._id;
    console.log(toupdate)

    Question.findById(eq.body._id, function (err, tank) {
      if (err){ 
                console.log(err.stack);
                return handleError(err);
            }
    toupdate.save(function (err){
    if (err){
        console.log(err.stack);
        return handleError(err);
        }
      });
    });
});
```

Comment: The second argument to the callback contains the response. Call like this `function(err,response)` then debug in `console.log(response.response)`. There keys in an object where "n" is the affected number of documents an "nMatched" is how many matched the query condition. Chances are you are not matching a document. Check your schema definition for the type of data you have in `_id`. Is this an existing collection? mongoose is expecting it to be called "questions" and not "question" by default, unless you override that.

Comment: got undefined for console.log(res.response); there is no problem with schema as I m using it to find and insert in another route in my project, the problem is occurring only in the update.

Comment: the `response.response` is the result of the `.update()` callback. Not the `res` in an express request.

Comment: same result undefined

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the support, tried your solution JohnnyHK but it didn't work, but found a way to update the document, had to assign fields of req.body to the fields of an object, here :

```
router.route('/results').post(function(req,res){
    Question.findOne(req.body._id, function (err, questions) {
      if (err) return handleError(err.stack);
               questions.question = req.body.question;
                questions.options = req.body.options; 
                questions.difficulty = req.body.difficulty;
                questions.type = req.body.type;
                questions.answer = req.body.answer;
                questions.domainof = req.body.domainof;
                questions.topic = req.body.topic;
                questions.weightage = req.body.weightage;        
                questions.created_by = req.body.created_by;
    questions.save(function (err){
    if (err) return handleError(err.stack);
        console.log(questions);
      });
    });
});
```